# Classic ASP: the "." in a jquery command (specifically, the dot in .val() ) sometimes gets replaced by TWO dots

Tags: jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

This is weird. There's a javascript function in classic ASP:

```
    function setcomment(whichone)
    {
        <% ' open the textarea for data-entry and move any existing text to it prior to editing %>
        current_comment = whichone; // save for the restore
        $("#clcomments_text").val($("#" + whichone + "_ItemDesc").val()); <% ' open the textarea and dump current comment in there and give it focus %>
        $('#clcomments').css('display','block');
        $("#clcomment_title").html($("#" + whichone + "_Title").val() + "&nbsp;" + "#" + $("#" + whichone + "_IssueNumber").val() + "&nbsp;ABC " + truncleft0($("#" + whichone + "_Condition").val()));
        $('#clcomments_text').focus();
    }
```

Note: clcomments is the id of a div. clcomments_title is the id of a span inside the div. clcomments_text is the id of a textarea inside the div.

Sometimes the webpage this is on stops working (I think the vbscript interpreter on the server dies when parsing one of the jquery lines because the symptom is that a totally different function doesn't work when it gets called -- i.e., the actual symptom does NOT involve the above-displayed setcomment()function.)

So anyway, I did a view-source and discovered the ".val" in the clcomments_title HTML assignment was being changed to "..val" !! How is this possible? The double-dot is NOT in the source. Even odder (and this tells me the problem may NOT be jquery related at all), there are 3 OTHER places in the view-source where a dot has been replaced by a double-dot (ALL 3 of these are in links where .asp has become ..asp.)

Has anybody ever seen something like this? I actually took the view-source and turned it into a static .htm and proved to myself if I removed the extra dots the functionality that was failing then worked.

Comment: Actually there isn't, the original coder has just used the ASP code blocks to hide the code comments for the JavaScript function, as they will be processed server-side and never rendered to the client. This is plain old client-side function, nothing else is being added server-side. As for the extra dots, this isn't the code causing it, you'd have to provide more detail for us to help much more.

Comment: It's a lot of client side javascript; what would you like to see? I agree the server is not to blame here, but what on earth would replace a few random dots with 2 dots? Could it matter whether or not there is markup in the textarea? Is .html() the proper way to place text into the textarea?

Comment: To debug this simply remove all those ASP comments, meaning any text between `<%` and `%>` which starts with a single quote, which means a comment in VBScript. If everything works great, you solved the problem without changing anything (and it will be s mystery forever as for why :)) if still no luck then make sure the code you see in View Source is the code you posted here, I don't think it is.

Comment: No, it's not the same. ".val" shows up as "..val" in the jquery html assignment line and the comments between the vbscript delimiters are not present. Re: getting rid of the ASP comments, I think that's a red-herring. OK, my bad for posting this as a vbscript issue -- clearly it is not, and yes, I will take your advice and strip out all the vbscript-ish elements. (The problem is the time it takes to replicate this error -- the set-up involves running through a lengthy process about 12 times.) Frankly, I think the problem is with the .html assignment or some other code that affects the markup.

Comment: @user1693404 did you get to the bottom of this issue?